# SQL Server int length property

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, int

I've got a SQL Server database. One of my tables has a column called `id` which is incremented automatically when I create a new project in a program that is connected to the database. Right now the highest id is 9175. Now I'm worried that the highest possible is is 9999. I checked the properties of the id column, see the below picture.

The "Length" property says 4. What does this mean for an int? Does it mean that the database will not accept an id of 10000? How can I find out?

[image]

Comment: Datatype `INT` in `Sql Server` can go as high as 2,147,483,647 please see documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and yes `Length` means size 4 Bytes for datatype `INT`

Comment: That `4` in Visual Studio  probably means 4 byte.

Comment: Just for fun, take a peek at https://www.quora.com/How-is-an-integer-value-stored-in-the-memory-in-C   This will give you a little insight as to how they pack 2.14B in 4 bytes.

Comment: The other hint is the _numeric precision_: the largest value occupies 10 decimal digits. That's different from saying that it stores 10 digit numbers. Since the range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 there are many larger 10 digit values it cannot handle.

Comment: I was confused... wish it said bytes rather than length when data type is int.  I now wonder, for datatypes Char or Varchar is the length the actual length in characters or does it still mean bytes?

Comment: Varchar: SQL varchar usually holds 1 byte per character and 2 more bytes for the length information.  So if for a int datatype the Length means bytes... what does Length mean for char or varchar if the definition here for varchar is true?  1 byte per character and 2 more bytes for the length?  Not sure what this means for datatypes not int.

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server [INT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has range:

> int   **-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)**    4 Bytes

Length 4 in case of INT is indicator of size(4 bytes).

Comment: OK, so the length of an int is the size of an int then?

Comment: The 4 is referring to 4 bytes as mentioned above.  In other words, you have no worry exceeding 9999.

Comment: If 10000 is your upper bound, might I suggest which has a range of `-2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)` and weighs in at a svelte 2 bytes (instead of 4)? tl;dr - choose the right data type for your use case.